# Unable to load Silverlight in angular2 when embedded in a component

Tags: silverlight, angular

**Current behavior**
When embedding and loading Silverlight.xap directly inside an HTML page, it works fine. But when we move same code inside a component, it won't load the Silverlight. DOM in both cases, i.e. embedding and loading through HTML and through component, doesn't show any difference.

**Code of Silverlight-app.Component.HTML Page**
When we load this page directly, i.e. localhost/OurApp/Silverlight-app.Component.HTML, silverlight content gets loaded and it works fine. But when we open index.html in browser (which is main component of our angular2 and Silverlight-app.Component.HTML page is child component of index.html), it don't load silverlight content.

```html
<section>    
    <div>
        <object id="silverlightControlHost" data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2"
                width="100%" height="100%" style="min-height: 100%; height: 1000px">            
            <param name="source" value="clientbin/SilverlightApp.xap"/>
            <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
            <param name="background" value="white" />
            <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="5.0.61118.0" />
            <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />            
            <param name="Windowless" value="true" />
            <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=5.0.61118.0" style="text-decoration: none">
                <img src="images/slmedallion.png" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style: none" />
            </a>
        </object>
        <iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility: hidden; height: 0px; width: 0px;
    border: 0px"></iframe>
        <iframe id="desktop" style="visibility: hidden; height: 0px; width: 0px; border: 0px"></iframe>
    </div>
</section>
```

**Expected/desired behavior**
Embedding and loading Silverlight component should have same behavior irrespective of loading through HTML or through component.

**What is the motivation / use case for changing the behavior?**
We are migrating our Silverlight application to Angular2. As complete migration will take months, we are keeping some of the silverlight modules as well.

**Images for better understanding of the issue**
[image: SilverlightHTML Page]

[image: Index HTML Page]

[image: Silverlight DOM]

[image: Index DOM]

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9660

Comment: Do you get any message in the browser console about removed content (sanitization)?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/1RFE6BUA6UUmwYhPwTne?p=preview at least shows the same "Get Microsoft Silverlight" link for me.

Comment: No, it is not giving any message in the browser console about removed content (sanitization).

And generally "Get Microsoft Silverlight" message will come if we don't have silverlight installed in our machine or have lower version than mentioned in the code which is 5.0.61118.0.
I have silverlight installed in my machine but when I am opening plnkr.co in IE 10, it is throwing error saying JSON is not supported by IE10.

Comment: Sounds like an IE problem. Have you tried in another browser?

Comment: Yes in chrome it shows "Get Microsoft Silverlight" but chrome has stopped supporting silverlight, only IE supports silverlight. I checked your code, when we create HTML file with same code as you write under template in src/app.ts file file, it works. But when we try to load it through component as you are doing, it don't work.

Comment: I have added four images, hope it explains the issue in better way. 1st image is of when we load silverlight-app.component.html directly in the browser, it shows the Silverlight sign in page. I am able to login in it and do all functionality. So it is working fine. 2nd image is of when we load index.html, it only shows blank white space, which means it is not loading the Silverlight. 3rd and 4th images shows the DOM of loading SilverlightHTML page and IndexHTML page respectively.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38131161/angular2-silverlight-pass-url-inside-a-container-to-a-silverlight-object?noredirect=1#comment63694082_38131161

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this example does exactly what you need :)

https://github.com/lohiarahul/Angular2-Silverlight-Starter