# Angular2-Silverlight: Pass URL inside a container to a silverlight object

Tags: javascript, silverlight, typescript, angular, routes

I am currently rewriting a silverlight application to Angular2. In the process, I need to keep running the existing silverlight application alongside the new Angular2 application.

So I have a parent container which nests a 'html'/'silverlight' container based on a hashed route.

But since, the silverlight application is now loaded inside a component, it cannot read the URL and the existing routing is broken. Is there any way, I could pass the URL change event inside the nested silverlight component?

I have uploaded the code here:

https://github.com/lohiarahul/Angular2-Silverlight-Starter

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38069230/unable-to-load-silverlight-in-angular2-when-embedded-in-a-component

Comment: I believe that my code sample is a solution to the issue above. I have achieved loading the silver-light in a container. What I need is for the silver-light to detect the URL change and route independently as it was working directly inside the browser before.

Comment: I see, so I should link here from the other question :D